# how to customize thumb of seek bar

Tags: android, seekbar

I want to display a `TextView` just *above* thumb of the `SeekBar` that will display the current progress of seek bar. As we move the thumb forward and backward the `TextView` will also move with thumb (the `TextView` should also be above the thumb).

Please provide any clue, code snippet are always welcome.

Answer (score 10):

Moving the *text* can even more easily done by setting the `padding` for the `TextView` as:

```
int xPos = ((SeekbarInstance.getRight() - SeekbarInstance.getLeft()) * SeekbarInstance.getProgress()) / SeekbarInstance.getMax();
textViewInstance.setPadding(xPos, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Layout of your activity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- Main context -->
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <SeekBar android:id="@+id/skbSample" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:max="35">
        </SeekBar>
    </LinearLayout>
        <!-- For display value -->
    <AbsoluteLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:text="0" 
            android:id="@+id/txvSeekBarValue" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:background="#FF777777"
            android:visibility = "invisible">
        </TextView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Initialize your controls on create:

```
mTxvSeekBarValue = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txvSeekBarValue);
mSkbSample = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.skbSample);
mSkbSample.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {       
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            ShowSeekValue((int)event.getX(), mTxvSeekBarValue.getTop());
            mTxvSeekBarValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);   
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            ShowSeekValue((int)event.getX(), mTxvSeekBarValue.getTop());
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            mTxvSeekBarValue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Function will move your value:

```
private void ShowSeekValue(int x, int y)
{
    if(x > 0 && x < mSkbSample.getWidth())
    {
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, x, y);
        mTxvSeekBarValue.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a better way. Derived from the sample:

```
mTxvSeekBarValue = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txvSeekBarValue);
mSkbSample = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.skbSample);
mSkbSample.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {       
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            int progress = mSkbSample.getProgress();
    mTxvSeekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress).toCharArray(), 0, String.valueOf(progress).length());   
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            int progress = mSkbSample.getProgress();
    mTxvSeekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress).toCharArray(), 0, String.valueOf(progress).length());  
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

There you don't need any additional method and the ACTION_UP event has no important effect on the result.